# Sets which are strictly $\Sigma_n$ but not $\Sigma_n$-complete

Tags: soft-question, computability

This question is about classifying the complexity of subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ in the arithmetical hierarchy. Empirically, it seems that whenever you can show $A$ is, say, $\Sigma_n$, then $A$ turns out to be $\Sigma_n$-complete (i.e. for any other $\Sigma_n$ set $B$, there is a many-one reduction $h\colon A \leq_m B$). Or at least, when you give a reasonable definition of $A$.

This is the case for many index sets, e.g. $\mathrm{TOT} = \{ e: \varphi_e$ total$\}$, $\mathrm{INF} = \{ e: W_e$ infinite$\}$, etc. Here, $\varphi_e$ list the partial computable functions, and $W_e$ the c.e. sets. Unpacking the definition shows that $\mathrm{TOT}$ and $\mathrm{INF}$ are both $\Pi_2$, and they both turn out to be $\Pi_2$-complete.

It seems there must be sets that are strictly $\Sigma_n$ but not $\Sigma_n$-complete, and I'm sure some sort of forcing argument could be used to construct one. What I'm more interested in is if there are **natural examples** of such things. That is, sets that one could conceivably care about for reasons other than they are strictly $\Sigma_n$ but not $\Sigma_n$-complete. E.g. index sets such as $\mathrm{TOT}$ or $\mathrm{INF}$.

*(of course, examples for $\Pi_n$ or $\Delta_n$ are equally fine)*

Comment: An aside: up to Turing equivalence rather than many-one equivalence there are no known examples. I believe the same is true for many-one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: strange. Is there an argument as to why, or we just don't know any examples?

Comment: I don't really think there are any *good* arguments. That said, we do have some theorems which give limits on our ability to construct intermediate-complexity objects. For example, see [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~marks/notes/001-is_the_turing_jump_unique.pdf). Given these results, a natural intermediate degree would have to have some feature which fundamentally doesn't relativize. That said there are candidates: it's consistent with our knowledge so far that Hilbert's tenth problem for $\mathbb{Q}$ is such a set, and "relativized $\mathbb{Q}$" doesn't make sense.